# data-role breaks "for loop' why

Tags: javascript, for-loop

When adding data-role="listview" to this html:

```
<ul id="mylinks" class="options" data-role="listview">
```

It breaks my 'for loop'. I checked 'lis.length' with an alert and it's still holding the number value. I'm also using jquery mobile js.

Why is my 'for loop' not working when data-role is added and how can I get around this. Is there alternate way of running this loop.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function()
{
    var ul = document.getElementById("mylinks");
    var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    alert(lis.length);
    var url = "http://" + window.location.host + "/mobile/";
    var NEWurl = "http://www.sportingpulse.com/mobile/";
    for( var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++ );
    {
        lis.item(i).childNodes[0].href = lis.item(i).childNodes[0].href.replace(url,     NEWurl);
        alert("working")
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you already checked the error console from FireFox, Chrome or Safari?

Comment: Why do you need to use `.replace()`? Why not just assign the URL?  And are you certain that the first child node of the `<li>` elements is really an `<a>`?  Things like newlines or whitespace will result in text nodes in the DOM.

Comment: Pointy was right when he said that you can't be sure that the next chilnode is a link. Use: 'lis.item(i).getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href' instead of 'lis.item(i).childnode[0].href'

Answer (score 2):

You've got an unwelcome semi-colon

```
for( var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++ );
```

Should be

```
for( var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++ )
```

Comment: Yes that was it. Adding a comment, that he just removing the semi colon from for() would have been enough ^^